# Parameter types of dynamic interface invocation in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, constraints, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement some typesafety for writing signalR hubs in my project. I want to create an abstract base class which provides typesafety for the derived classes. I should provide a method `Invoke` which infers the type arguments from the string names of the functions from the interfaces, which are provided when deriving a class.

A minimal sample implementation looks like this (here, the method in Question is named `testInvoke`). TestServices is derived from AbstractTestService with the interface NotifyServer:

```
// interface definition
interface NotifyServer {
    Register(channel: number) : boolean;
}

// extracts function names from referenced interfaces
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
        [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

abstract class AbstractTestService<TServer>{
    public testInvoke<
    TMethod extends FunctionPropertyNames<TServer>,
    TCall extends TServer[TMethod],
    TParameters extends Parameters<TCall>,   // unsure what is upsetting Typescript here ...
    TReturn extends ReturnType<TCall>        // ... and here
    >(method: TMethod, ...args: TParameters): Promise<TReturn> {
       return new Promise<TReturn>(() => console.log("test"));
    }
}

// When implementing TestService, the testInvoke method resolves correctly although typescript marks
// TCall as an Error in AbstractTestService
class TestService extends AbstractTestService<NotifyServer> implements NotifyServer {
    public Register(channel: number) : boolean {
        this.testInvoke('Register', 1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

this used to work for me in older versions of typescript, but unfortunately now it throws the following error:

```
error TS2344: Type 'TCall' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'TClient[TMethod]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type 'TClient[FunctionPropertyNames<TClient>]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
      Type 'TClient[TClient[keyof TClient] extends Function ? keyof TClient : never]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
        Type 'TClient[keyof TClient]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
          Type 'TClient[string] | TClient[number] | TClient[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
            Type 'TClient[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.

            TParameters extends Parameters<TCall>
```

That leaves me puzzled and I am not shure was causes this problem.

A typescript playground with this code can be found here: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUATWirmuAPaQBQUcSaGAcoQYgJ4DKCAbgqAN4mi%20gBKsAObgAzhQAUqABbJIkWABsAXKEgBXALYAjBAEpQq7YUKLYcgNwkAviTIwEKdKFr0GAYUXhYMLjz7UsADuACLI0MgACoTkEgAOMTCqGjr6qqwxmFa2JCCgsAAe0PBo0KKgiOqQqATEasiasOWI8ISaoPA4CD7omBAOlOiiJNAMcRgAYlU1RJCRrePwo9QNTQA8ACoAfKAAvH58h6AA2gDS-aAA1rAMhIigGwC6qhtnj-lFPpjlU9W1kKAAPygc7JWDseDZY7XW73J5WXJgACCoCChHglygQlAogacTMoHUoixoGg0gwl0ghCCAPIjioLjo4EYLHgEMRoHJnQANKTyQ93MhFIpSWMMGJQKh0Z0aooGB0mqZ2JgSNhUIpkJ0KtN-qSmtBfqgAIxrfy8DYAWVgZMIfUKcEg31Ahv%2080Ii2Wq1Ea1czOYbAQW25ZoFQpF9q%205V9LID8GOlut0ltj2Dhw2kU1qwo5QjjvKGZKjWzm0FwqDIY2gmg6ngANzTqrNcgGzFJbDWxIWwkRaTmBeVptmF5ADpR5qhKIXgWswhRHoXo3a1YzNAFaJ1IpV-s4OJDUaJAByQQicQIA%208gBMegReRRmjwmiFHzxBMQ6NAmnlcVa2jMmmHDz6qyrDgM4UBcvg5RkhgSLaOIJQ1BsQFsKBGByH0QqiIQfIYDu0AAJKQBk1wfomtrDhyTDYVAp7IH0dyMm4wEILy0FahKxByjhoBCD4CCgQ8zHwJy3QARs-KjOMa6mOouooOAijlFAobChRyBwcUpSShqojlLB8GlEh4jAahmxCVs3CHHE6i-gJeGEcRsCmmmA69h8DpOi6sxuh6DArI03obOZqZ8Bspbhp8eaCbG8aucmIXmtORazu5kagEl1qzm2Za8rweRVOuWpBLIq4SuocSiNaBCQNiLbjKIqDwOAcSrlyGCjhRaaLnWkUNtaTZ1U5YXtkcfB5B1oDoSJnQhl2Pa2v2ZFDqAHXjpODwZdm87pa096VZs3U7JZo2dNWtZqMEO1tGIQ2HRIEgGLsOxSpAWFmMOiiEEIEgAER4T9ejXiGtg5HkADq5K0po%20KwI0MAkkZ0AmegrESfqDmECR819J0b3sOUUrwDK0BcUKNrqEI0iivVjXNauj4YsMeTDcKk3lHIoAAKJE%20%20yn6ZpiHIWyqEkOqyC6YBxkoc49Z6RpCHQIjyNOdG-psoGEDQ3%20PhlIxfpCQcfDWbZqACMIYiSDIcgKCoahaLo8AGEYJhmBzx2jWSYjDvZRGY7Ah7HhbZ68kaQOjbwp1NqS8DqLAViHCDQA)

Any suggestions or hints in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE that demonstrates your issue.  That way we could get right to work on finding a solution instead of having to spend effort on seeing the problem in the first place.  Right now I just get all kinds of errors unrelated to your question.  If you do decide to [edit] to do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Hi, I have reworked the question and added a link to a typescript playground containing sample code. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Generally speaking the compiler cannot perform higher order generic conditional type analysis; in particular it cannot know that `T[FunctionPropertyNames[T]]` will be a function type for generic `T`; see [ms/TS#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992). You say this used to work on "older versions" of TypeScript, but I'm skeptical of that. To fix it I'd change the code to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnbAeN); does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Ping me via @jcalz)